# Data won't store for all input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I remove `inputAuthor` and `inputNumber`, then it will add whatever is inputted for the first field. However the other two are unresponsive. Are they being blocked ? I am still new to coding. I am following the odin project and trying to build a simple library that stores the title, author and page numbers.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Library</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Urbanist:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Library</h1>
</div>

<form>
    <input id="item" type="text" placeholder="Title" required />
    <input id ="author-input" type="text"  placeholder="Author" required />
    <input id="number-input" type="number" placeholder="Pages" required/>
    
  </form>
  
  <h2>Book info</h2>
  
  <table id="table">
      <td id="td"></td>
  </table>
  
  <button>Clear All</button>
```

javascript

```
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const input = document.getElementById('item')
const inputAuthor = document.getElementById('author-input')
const inputNumber = document.getElementById('number-input')
const table = document.getElementById('table')



let itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))
  : []


localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))

const tdMaker = (text) => {
  const td = document.createElement('td')
  td.textContent = text
  td.style.backgroundColor = ("white")
  td.style.border = ("solid")
  td.style.fontWeight = ("bold")
  table.appendChild(td)
  table.appendChild(td)
  table.appendChild(td)
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  itemsArray.push(input.value)
  itemsArray.push(inputAuthor.value)
  itemsArray.push(inputNumber.value)
  localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
  tdMaker(input.value)
  tdMaker(inputAuthor.value)
  tdMaker(inputNumber.value)
  input.value = ''
  inputAuthor.value = ''
  inputNumber.value = ''
})

data.forEach((item) => {
  tdMaker(item)
})

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  localStorage.clear()
  while (table.firstChild) {
    table.removeChild(table.firstChild)
  }
})
```

Comment: This seems redundant `localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))`

Comment: This does not store anything `localStorage.clear()
  while (table.firstChild) {
    table.removeChild(table.firstChild)
  }` nor does it update the itemsArray

Comment: And why not use an object: `itemsArray.push({ input: input.value, author: Author.value, 
 number : inputNumber.value})`

Comment: And where is the row? `const tdMaker = (text) => {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');  const td = document.createElement('td')`